# How can I mirror the screen on my Windows 10 laptop to my Linux device?

Tags: debian, wifi, windows, screencasting

I have Windows 10 installed on one of my laptops.

I also have a Linux (Debian Bullseye) device connected to a big display through HDMI.

My laptop and my Linux device are connected to my router through Wi-Fi and LAN, respectively.

I want to mirror (duplicate, not extend) my Windows screen wirelessly to my Linux device so I can view it on a bigger screen.

Windows 10 already has wireless screencasting support, and I don't want to install anything extra in it. But I am free to install/run stuff on the Debian running on the Linux device.

The built-in screencast software of W10 should be able to find, connect, and stream display to the Linux device over Wi-Fi. How can I achieve this?

I tried running [Miraclecast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) on the Linux device, but it requires me to stop the network manager, which isn't acceptable as I need an internet connection on the Linux device.

Comment: magic is not part of science whatever the chosen screen-sharing-client you will use it will have to  be installed at least on the "master" side so the machine that shares her screen  no way  to avoid that. Also if you need more than a sharing like remote control you will need tools and permissions set end-to-end  (on each host+route)  and have need a client on bath host to be installed & compatible each other of course.  a light solution might be tinyVNC & similar tools any other solution might need network temporary interruption as far as I know.

Comment: @francoisP, you are correct. There's no magic. In this case, the chosen client is Windows 10's built-in screencasting. Need something(s) on that Linux machine that can talk with it and throw the stream on the connected display. Need help in figuring out what this something(s) can be.